# Simple Error Question

Tags: computational-mathematics

I have a question which asks to find the absolute error and then asks if the actual error agrees with the theoretical error bound. Am I missing something or are absolute and actual error the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute error is the magnitude of the difference between the exact value and the approximation, while the actual error is the difference between the accepted value and the measured value of a quantity.

Comment: the accepted value? would that be the final approximation? so they would be the same but the actual error could be negative